# Php 5.5 performance windows vs linux. Why so different?

Tags: php, linux, performance, azure, benchmarking

I have been tested this benchmark script http://www.php-benchmark-script.com/
on linux and windows machines. Yes.Better to test on the same hardware but i cant.

Difference is very interesting. I run php from command line:

**Shared hosting:**

```
Xeon E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz
PHP version : 5.5.17
Platform : Linux
--------------------------------------
test_math                 : 0.989 sec.
test_stringmanipulation   : 1.006 sec.
test_loops                : 0.587 sec.
test_ifelse               : 0.487 sec.
--------------------------------------
Total time:               : 3.069 sec.
```

**My local machine:**

```
i5 3570К 3.4 (overclock to 3.7Ghz)
PHP version : 5.5.17
Platform : WINNT (win7-64)
--------------------------------------
test_math                 : 0.838 sec.
test_stringmanipulation   : 1.984 sec.
test_loops                : 0.622 sec.
test_ifelse               : 0.394 sec.
--------------------------------------
Total time:               : 3.838 sec.
```

**Windows AZURE  Standard_A2 (2 core, 3,5 RAM)**

```
PHP version : 5.5.17
Platform : WINNT
--------------------------------------
test_math                 : 2.117 sec.
test_stringmanipulation   : 4.591 sec.
test_loops                : 1.949 sec.
test_ifelse               : 1.436 sec.
--------------------------------------
Total time:               :10.093 sec.
```

**Windows AZURE  websites free**

```
PHP version : 5.5.14
Platform : WINNT
--------------------------------------
test_math                 : 2.238 sec.
test_stringmanipulation   : 4.485 sec.
test_loops                : 1.874 sec.
test_ifelse               : 1.292 sec.
--------------------------------------
Total time:               : 9.889 sec.
```

Why linux really much faster for PHP? 
Is it Xeon E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz just magic processor?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask Microsoft: they've spent a lot of time and effort in trying to get equivalent performance

Comment: Are you sure that your tests aren't better suited to a xeon processor? Not saying that linux has bad performance - but you should be testing this sort of thing on the same hardware :)

Comment: Are you shared hosting and local machines virtualized?

Comment: @Fluffeh yes. Look at this http://serebniti.ru/code/bench.php
And try to get this score on any windows machine. I think this is not simple. You can see that score dependence on CPU GHZ only. And linux add faster runtime for php.

Comment: @CSharpRocks hared hosting is virtualized (xen). Local machine is not. I cant testing windows on Xeon E5-2680 v2 (((

Comment: I think that this is a better test for the comparison of PHP performance, same hardware. http://www.paessler.com/tools/webstress/sample_performance_tests/comparing_php_script_performance_on_linux_and_windows

Comment: @Robobenklein I think hardware wise the comparison is much better but look at the Apache versions... That test setup can not be taken serious with a major Apache version difference! Even though I do think linux will outperform windows as a host for a webserver any time.